# Unable to view codebehind in a ascx file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, forum

I downloaded an open source project in ASP.NET language.

And I couldn't find any Codebehind file for example inside the Login.aspx the Codebehind is Login.aspx.cs but I cant find it anywhere in the source file. and the Line Codebehind="Login.aspx.cs" identified as "File Login.aspx.cs was not found" but yet the function is still working.

Where can I access those .cs file?

Comment: can you add the project download link here,or list of files in the project.

Comment: there u go bro.. http://www.sourcecodeonline.com/details/easy_forum_net.html

There is a .dll file in the Bin folder is it something to do with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that code you are looking for is compiled in DLL files. Try to get full source code instead of compiled one.

As mentioned by VKX, download link would help...

Comment: Yes there is a .dll file.. may i know how to decompile it?

Comment: Well... from your link it looks like paid software, so you should not decompile it. But of course, it is up to you. You can use [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) or any other free tool.

Comment: Thumbs up for this comment. Could not give a vote up as my reputation is low. Great Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the file exist on disk. It may not be included in the project.

You could view all files by clicking the "Show all files" button on top of solution explorer.

If the file does not exist on disk, or reside in some other folder, move it to the appropriate folder. If the file is missing, redownload/unpack it to the correct folder.

Answer (score 0):

For your confirmation once again recomplie the Application if application run successfuly then your file would be existed in the drive. As per your question, might be your application is working on the complied dll.

Just open the Login.aspx in the Visual studio just right click on the tab of the Login.aspx page and select the option "Open the Contaning folder". Check Login.aspx file is existed or not in that folder.

Comment: it's not available in the folder. But instead there is a .dll extension file in it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems You only have compiled website.So no *.cs file.

- You will be able to use website(host using IIS) but cannot change source code.
- To view the source code open .dll file using [DotPeek Decompiler](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or [RedGate Decompiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/)

and yes the download link provided in comment is broken.